# How to delete Gmail signatures

Tags: gmail

I have defined multiple signatures in Gmail, but want to delete some of them.
How do I do it? I have figured out how to blank them out, but want to actually delete them so that they don't get selected by accident.

Comment: You can only have a single signature. Do you mean canned responses?

Comment: I understand exactly what the OP is asking. It is possible to have multiple signatures defined in Gmail, one for each "Send mail as:" email address. The only way to delete the signature is to delete the "send mail as:" email address that the signature is associated with.

Answer (score 1):

Blanking the field out is the only way and gives the result you are looking for. You can only have one signature per email address; not sure what you mean by selecting one accidently.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to remove an old signature in my Gmail settings and can confirm there is no simple way to delete a signature. I think your best bet is to just clear out the old signature or select the No Signature option.  Not ideal at all.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the signature from Gmail you have to follow some steps.

1. First click on settings on the top right corner of your Gmail page.
2. Then click on the lab tab after clicking to the lab tab you find signature tweaks and enable that option by selecting the radio button.
3. Then click on the save changes buttons to save the changes made to the lab setting.

By the above process you can remove the signature from Gmail.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to vary with different versions of Gmail. None of the answers I found were very helpful.

To delete a signature or change default do the following:

1. Click the cog on top right of mail screen and select *Settings*
2. Select the *Accounts and Import* tab
3. Alongside *Send email as:* you will find current signatures. You can delete, edit and change default here.